# BeautifulSoup my for loop is printing the data in separate lines. How do i print it in 1 line

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have the following sample HTML table from a html file.
I am trying to print the text from the

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th class="failed">Fail</th>
            <th class="failed">Error</th>
            <th>Skip</th>
            <th>Success</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Regression_TestCase.RegressionProject_TestCase2.RegressionProject_TestCase2</td>
                <td class="failed">1</td>
                <td class="failed">9</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>219</td>
                <td>229</td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
            <td class="failed">1</td>
            <td class="failed">9</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>219</td>
            <td>229</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

My for loop is:

```
def extract_data_from_report():
    html_report = open(r"E:\projects\ClearCore\ClearCore Regression\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestReport\SeleniumTestReport.html",'r').read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report, "html.parser")
    print soup.find_all('th')
    print soup.find_all('td')

    for item in soup.find_all('th'):
        print item.text
```

The output is:

```
Class
Fail
Error
Skip
Success
Total
```

I would like the output to be like this:

```
Class Fail Error Skip Success Total
```

How do i print it all in 1 line?

Thanks, Riaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Python adds a newline every time you have a `print` statement.  If you add a comma at the end of your list of items to print, Python will instead add a space at the end with no newline.  What you need to do is this:

Replace

```
print item.text
```

with

```
print item.text,
```

You will also need a single `print` after everything in the list is printed (i.e. at the very end of your function).  This will put that terminating newline at the end of your list.

Comment: Do you know how i can exclude the <td> tags where it says Total?  i do not want this part printed out

Comment: My code is: td = soup.find_all('td')   for item in td:
        print item.text,

Comment: @RiazLadhani You want to print the contents of the `td` tags, except for those in the third `tr` (selecting that `tr` specifically because its first `td` contains Total)?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  I think you can use an index like when indexing a list.  I do not know the syntax to achieve this

Comment: That's going to be more complicated.  What you probably want to do is get `tr = soup.find_all('tr')`, test if the first child of that is a `td` that contains contains Total using `tr.firstChild().tag == 'td'` and `'Total' in tr.firstChild().contents`, and if it doesn't, print its children.